# interact (concat . sort lines) cba

Tags: haskell

Why is the code below not working- it is not giving the desired output.I want it to sort a string(e.g cba -> abc ) .After  I signal end of file with 
^D  i just get: cba .

```
import Data.List
import Data.Char
import System.IO (isEOF)


main =
   interact (concat . sort .lines)
```

Comment: You're breaking it up into lines, sorting the lines relative to each other, and putting them back together. How can you modify the `sort` invocation to sort `each` line?

Comment: `sort` here is being called at the type `[String] -> [String]`, but you want `[Char] -> [Char]` - i.e. the current `sort` is sorting the list of lines by lexicographical ordering on strings. Try `let sort' :: String -> String'; sort' = sort in interact (concat . sort' . lines)` - this gives you a type error, but should be a starting point for figuring this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want something more like:

```
import Data.List

main = interact (unlines . map sort . lines)
```

This sorts each line entered.